AJAX POST misformatting base64 string
I am having trouble getting an AJAX POST to correctly upload/return my base64 string to/from my SQL database. When I return the string from my database via AJAX, I receive exactly the same base64 string, but with random line breaks. Sadly, these line breaks make the string unusable.
At the top of the console you can see the incorrectly formatted base64, while the bottom is correctly formatted.
Photo Here
When I view the base64 string in my SQL database, it is incorrectly formatted, which leads me to believe the initial AJAX upload is where the issue occurs. I have my SQL datatype set to MEDIUMTEXT, so that could be an issue, but I saw no difference when I changed the datatype.
//Getting the base64 string
let canvas = picCheckIn.getContext("2d")
let dataURL = canvas.canvas.img.src
//Hard-coding the base64 string to the image's source
imgPreviousIn.src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A...<Rest of base64 string>"

//Assigning the AJAX base64 string to the image's source
let req = Ajax(<POST query here...>)
let results = JSON.parse(req.responseText)
imgPreviousIn.src=results[0][0]

The error code I get:
GET data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gKgSUNDX1...  net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Please show the controller code that's creating the JSON with the base64 string in it.

Suggestion - Don't store image source in database. Store just relative path to file, show image links. E.g. if I upload 200 images with 20Mb size each, than your MEDIUMTEXT will ruin image data and your database will be inflated for no reason

which leads me to believe the initial AJAX upload is where the issue occurs you can determine that by inspecting the request in the browser dev tools - and I doubt that's where it is happening

The culprit was the SQL database. My database was converting plus signs to whitespace, and thus removing the plus signs.
This is fixed by using string.replaceAll("+","%2B") before sending the string via AJAX call. I also found that it works best if you run separate AJAX calls for each string you are calling.
